# A way to check Oracle finished sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, import, docker

I've got Docker Compose cluster and one of the containers is Oracle 12c. There is `schema.sql` file to initialize the db. I would like my application to wait until the db executes all the sql. How can I do it in an automatic fashion with bash?

Thank you very much for any suggestions!